# In $A[X]$, show that $S_{uX+a}$ is an automorphism if and only if $u\in A^*$ for $u,a\in A$.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory

$A$ is a ring (we suppose rings to be commutative and to have unity), $A[X]$ the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $A$ and $S_{b}:A[X]\longrightarrow A[b]$ represents the substitution homomorphism by $b$. Here we consider $S_{uX+a}:A[X] \longrightarrow A[uX+a]=A[X]$ with $u,a \in A$.

One implication is clear. If $u\in A^*$ ($u$ is a unity), then we can show quite easy that the substitution $S_{u^{-1}X-u^{-1}a}$ is an inverse endomorphism, and therefore is $S_{uX+a}$ an automorphism.

I would like to know different ideas for the other implication.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other one is a bit more tricky. Let us call $S_{uX+a}$ as $S$. Suppose that $S$ is an automorphism. Then, $\exists g\in A[X]$ such that $S(g)=X$. Let $g=\sum_{i=0}^n g_i X^i$, $\Rightarrow$ $S(g)=\sum_{i=0}^n g_i (uX+a)^i=\sum_{i=0}^n a^ig_i + Xu(\sum_{i=1}^n g_ia^{i-1})+\pi(X) =X$ where $\pi(X)$ represents the other monomials where the degree of $X$ is higher than $1$. Since the polynomial representation is unique, we have $$\sum_{i=0}^n a^ig_i=0,\pi(X)=0$$ $$ Xu(\sum_{i=1}^n g_ia^{i-1})=X$$
From the last one, we deduce $u(\sum_{i=1}^n g_ia^{i-1})=1$, and therefore $u\in A^*$ with $u^{-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n g_ia^{i-1}$.